# Scala: Button in Table Cell does not "fire" Action

Tags: scala, scala-swing

I've got a little Problem: I want to have `Buttons` in some of the cells of my `Table`. As rendering component I return a `Button` with the following code: (theres application specific and debugging code in this example but you'll get the picture)

```
class LivingTreeButton(lt:LivingTree[_], client:TableBehaviourClient) extends Button(Action("xx") {
  println("fire!")
  lt.expanded = !lt.expanded
  client.refresh
}){
  println("I print therefore I am")
}
```

now when I scroll to one of the `Buttons` in the `Table` I see the "I print therefore I am" printouts and I do see the buttons with the "xx" text. But when I press one of the buttons nothing happens and I don't even see the "fire!" printouts.

It doesn't work neither, when I define the `Action` in the `Buttons` body instead of the constructor.

As further background info:
I'm not blocking the tables `Events` or anything. I only have a to listeners set up in `JTable`

```
 peer.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(behaviourWorker)
 peer.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(behaviourWorker)
```

and only temporarily block one of my own events in the `Tables` subclass:

```
listenTo(this.selection)
reactions += {
  case e@TableRowsSelected(_,_,true) => if(!blockSelectionEvents) publish(PimpedTableSelectionEvent(this))
}
```

has any of you ever struggled with the same problem or has any idea what might be going wrong. After 2 hours od resultless debugging I would be thankfull for ANY hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I got it. Didn't know that I have to add a [`TableCellEditor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html) to catch the events. Doesn't really work yet but I'm sure that's it.